# Product Grid Showing Please select products for attributes update while updating attributes from mass action

Tags: product, massaction, product-grid

I am getting error "Please select products for attributes update", when I try to update attributes form mass action in product grid. see below image-

[image]

I have checked the check box for products for which I want to update attribute still why it is showing error?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have installed marketplace like cedcmsmarket.
In my case cedcmsmarketplace is creating this issue.

Comment: No, I haven't added any module like that.